# Parent gets EOF when child quits after getting an EOF?

Tags: c, linux, fork, eof

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {
    int ch;
    pid_t p = fork();

    if (p == 0) {
        do {
            ch = getchar();
        } while (ch >= 0);
        return 0;
    }
    int s;
    waitpid(p, &s, 0);
    printf("A done\n");
    p = 0;
    do {
        ch = getchar();
    } while (ch >= 0 && (++p));
    printf("chars: %d\n", p);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's a minimal example code. Theoretically it should read some characters until EOF, and print `A done`, and read some more characters, and show you how many there are after `A done`.

However, on my Windows Subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu 18.04), when I hit Ctrl-D for the first time, **both** the child and parent processes quit (receives an EOF). The output I get is something like

```
asdfghjkl
^DA done
chars: 0
```

Why is that? And how do I fix this?

Comment: They share the same input stream.

Comment: @user3386109 I'm able to send something to the parent if I use GNU readline in the parent - any solution?

Answer (score 0):

In a `fork(2)`, file descriptors are `dup(2)`ed, so they share the same file pointer, and what one of the process reads, is not read by the other, as a consequence of this.